# Find distinct number for a group of columns partitioned by another column in table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I am working with SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7.

I need to find distinct number of a group of columns partitioned by another column.

Table:

```
ID  value1 value2 value3 
--------------------------
358 32169   31984  9716 
358 9441    94     97897
235 32169   31984  9716 
235 8464    8454   36197
235  8646   97     36879
```

Result:

```
ID   distinct_num_of_value1_value2_value3  
------------------------------------------
358            2      // 358 has two distinct rows with v1 v2 v3 
235            3      // 235 has 3 distinct rows with v1 v2 v3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain this line `find distinct number of a group of columns partitioned by another column`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
select
    id,
    count(distinct cast(value1 as varchar(32)) + '_' + cast(value2 as varchar(32)) + '_' + cast(value3 as varchar(32))) as distinct_num_of_value1_value2_value3
from
    YourTable
group by
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Test table:

```
DECLARE @t table(ID int,  value1 int, value2 int, value3  int)
INSERT @t values
  (358,32169,31984,9716),(358,9441,94,97897),
  (235,32169,31984,9716),(235,8464,8454,36197),
  (235,8646,97,36879)
```

Query:

```
--use group by

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    id, value1, value2, value3
   FROM
     @t
  GROUP BY 
    id, value1, value2, value3
)
SELECT 
  count(*) cnt, 
    id
FROM
  CTE
GROUP BY
  id

--or use distinct

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct id, value1, value2, value3
   FROM
     @t
)
SELECT 
  count(*) cnt, 
    id
FROM
  CTE
GROUP BY
  id
```

Result:

```
cnt id
3   235
2   358
```